# How to make an Adjacency List using a vector of vector pair in C++?

Tags: c++, list, vector, graph, std-pair

I'm trying to create an Adjacency list using a vector of vector pair, and whenever I run the code it stops working. For now, I'm only trying to add the first pair in the Adjacency List "AdjList". Is there a better way or any modifications to do it ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
typedef pair<int, int> ii;
typedef vector<ii> vii;
vector <vii> AdjList;

int main()
{
    ii v= make_pair(5,4);
    AdjList[0][0]=v;
    cout << v.first<< endl;
}
```

Comment: What you should have is probably this instead,

    `typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > adjList;`

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning a value to an empty vector:

```
AdjList[0][0] = v; // Problematic
```

Try to use [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or resize the size of two nested vectors.

Another way is using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you know the size of the graph:

```
const int N = 10;

std::array<std::array<int, N>, N>  AdjList;

...

AdjList[0][0] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`:

```
std::set<std::pair<int,int>> adj_list;
adj_list.emplace(0,0);
adj_list.emplace(0,1);
for(auto& p:adj_list)
    std::cout<<p.first<<"-"<<p.second<<std::endl;
```